# What is the purpose of cache an RDD in Apache Spark?

Tags: caching, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I am new for Apache Spark and I have couple of basic questions in spark which I could not understand while reading the spark material. Every materials have their own style of explanation. I am using PySpark Jupyter notebook on Ubuntu to practice.

As per my understanding, When I run the below command, the data in the testfile.csv is partitioned and stored in memory of the respective nodes.( actually I know its a lazy evaluation and it will not process until it sees action command ), but still the concept is

```
rdd1 = sc.textFile("testfile.csv")
```

My question is when I run the below transformation and action command, where does the rdd2 data will store.

1.Does it stores in memory?

```
rdd2 = rdd1.map( lambda x: x.split(",") )

rdd2.count()
```

I know the data in rdd2 will available till I close the jupyter notebook.Then what is the need of cache(), anyhow rdd2 is available to do all transformation. I heard after all the transformation the data in memory is cleared, what is that about?

2. Is there any difference between keeping RDD in memory and cache()

   rdd2.cache()

Comment: Maybe a little off topic, but I encountered this thread with a correlated problem: My Pyspark decided to run the built-in-udf within the rdd EVERYtime the rdd or the dfs, that were built from this rdd, were called. The rdd.cache() stopped this behaviour. Even more, the udf stops running again and again exactly from the point where the .cache() is called. So, the earlier you detect the multiple-calling-rdd or multiple-calling-df, the better.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Does it stores in memory?

When you run a spark transformation via an *action* (`count`, `print`, `foreach`), then, and only then is your graph being materialized and in your case the file is being consumed. `RDD.cache` purpose it to make sure that the result of `sc.textFile("testfile.csv")` is available in memory and isn't needed to be read over again.

Don't confuse the *variable* with the actual operations that are being done behind the scenes. Caching allows you to re-iterate the data, making sure it is in memory (if there is sufficient memory to store it in it's entirety) if you want to re-iterate the said RDD, and as long as you've set the right *storage level* (which defaults to `StorageLevel.MEMORY`). [From the documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#rdd-persistence) (Thanks @RockieYang):

> In addition, each persisted RDD can be stored using a different
>   storage level, allowing you, for example, to persist the dataset on
>   disk, persist it in memory but as serialized Java objects (to save
>   space), replicate it across nodes, or store it off-heap in Tachyon.
>   These levels are set by passing a StorageLevel object (Scala, Java,
>   Python) to persist(). The cache() method is a shorthand for using the
>   default storage level, which is StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY (store
>   deserialized objects in memory).
>
> You can mark an RDD to be persisted using the persist() or cache()
>   methods on it. The first time it is computed in an action, it will be
>   kept in memory on the nodes. Spark’s cache is fault-tolerant – if any
>   partition of an RDD is lost, it will automatically be recomputed using
>   the transformations that originally created it.

---

> Is there any difference between keeping RDD in memory and cache()

As stated above, you *keep it* in memory via `cache`, as long as you've provided the right storage level. Otherwise, it won't necessarily be kept in memory at the time you want to re-use it.

Comment: I think this is only true when storage level is MEMORY_ONLY

Comment: @RockieYang What are you referring to by *this*? The fact that `RDD`s will be kept in memory?

Comment: I am refer to http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#rdd-persistence

Comment: Pleasure. I think the Spark API is a bit misleading. `Persist this RDD with the default storage level (MEMORY_ONLY).`. I would prefer like `Persist this RDD according to storage level configuration, by default is MEMORY_ONLY`

Comment: @RockieYang Creating pull requests is always welcome :)

Comment: @downvoter - Feel free to let me know what's wrong with this answer.

Comment: I found the answer - Module 2: Spark Tutorial Lab, Part 7: Caching RDDs and storage options from the below link https://docs.cloud.databricks.com/docs/latest/courses/index.html